# AVG(DATEDIFF(d,Tabl1.date1,MIN(Table2.date1))) T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions, average

I am trying to create a report to provide data from a SQL Server database. I have 3 tables I am interested in, Client, Referral, Appointment. A client can have 1.* referrals and a referral can have 0.* appointments booked against it.

In my report I want to show the average time from a referral being received to 1st appointment.

Am trying the above in my stored procedure but receive "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Is there a slick way of getting this to work without sub query you can think of?

**Edit** Rough table structure below.

**Client**
ClientID INT IIDENTITY (pk)
Forename VARCHAR(50)
Surname VARCHAR(50)
DOB DATETIME

**Referral**
ReferralID INT IDENTITY (pk)
ClientID INT (fk)
ReferralRequestReceivedDate DATETIME
OrgaisationAreaId INT (fk)

**Appointment**
AppintmentID INT IDENTITY (pk)
ReferralId INT(fk)
AppointmentDate DATETIME
AttendanceTypeId INT (fk)
AppointmentTypeID INT (fk)

**AttendanceTypes**
AttendanceTypeID INT IDENTITY (pk)
Name VARCHAR(50)

**AppointmentTypes**
AppointmentTypeID INT IDENTITY (pk)
Name VARCHAR(50)

**OrganisationArea**
OrgaisationAreaId INT IDENTITY(pk)
Name VARCHAR(50)

My existing proc has counts for appointments attended by age and attendance type as below...

```
SELECT OA.Name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN AppointmentTypeId IN(1,3) 
               AND AppointmentDate BETWEEN '27 Jan 2013' AND '13 Apr 2013' 
               THEN AppointmentId END) AS AppsBooked,
AVG(DATEDIFF(d, ReferralRequestReceivedDate, MIN(A.AppointmentDate))) 
AS AvgAllocationWaitTime

FROM OrganisationAreas OA
LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients C
    ON OA.OrganisationAreaId = C.OrganisationAreaId
LEFT OUTER JOIN IaptReferrals R 
    ON C.ClientId = R.ClientId
LEFT OUTER JOIN IaptAppointments A
    ON R.IaptReferralId = A.Referral_IaptReferralId

GROUP BY OA.OrganisationAreaId, OA.Name
```

Comment: What is the structure of these tables?  What keys link them together?

Comment: why do you want this work without sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think a way without using sub query or cte..
but if you are ok with sub query, try this

```
SELECT OA.Name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN 
            AppointmentTypeId IN(1,3) AND AppointmentDate BETWEEN '27 Jan 2013' AND '13 Apr 2013' THEN AppointmentId 
      END) AS AppsBooked,
AVG(DATEDIFF(d, ReferralRequestReceivedDate, sq.MinAppointmentDate)) AS AvgAllocationWaitTime
FROM OrganisationAreas OA
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT  C.OrganisationAreaId, MIN(A.AppointmentDate) MinAppointmentDate 
    FROM IaptAppointments A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IaptReferrals R ON R.IaptReferralId = A.Referral_IaptReferralId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients C ON C.ClientId = R.ClientId 
    GROUP BY C.OrganisationAreaId
) sq ON sq.OrganisationAreaId = OA.OrganisationAreaId
GROUP BY OA.OrganisationAreaId, OA.Name
```

or cte version:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT C.OrganisationAreaId, MIN(A.AppointmentDate) MinAppointmentDate 
    FROM IaptAppointments A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IaptReferrals R ON R.IaptReferralId = A.Referral_IaptReferralId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients C ON C.ClientId = R.ClientId
    GROUP BY C.OrganisationAreaId
)
SELECT OA.Name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN 
            AppointmentTypeId IN(1,3) AND AppointmentDate BETWEEN '27 Jan 2013' AND '13 Apr 2013' THEN AppointmentId 
      END) AS AppsBooked,
AVG(DATEDIFF(d, ReferralRequestReceivedDate, cte.MinAppointmentDate)) AS AvgAllocationWaitTime
FROM OrganisationAreas OA
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte ON cte.OrganisationAreaId = OA.OrganisationAreaId
GROUP BY OA.OrganisationAreaId, OA.Name
```

Comment: Top advice Ethan. Cheers. Used CTE version and love it.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
SELECT OA.Name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN AppointmentTypeId IN(1,3) 
               AND AppointmentDate BETWEEN '27 Jan 2013' AND '13 Apr 2013' 
               THEN AppointmentId END) AS AppsBooked,
AVG(DATEDIFF(d, ReferralRequestReceivedDate, MIN(A.AppointmentDate))) 
AS AvgAllocationWaitTime

FROM OrganisationAreas OA
LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients C
    ON OA.OrganisationAreaId = C.OrganisationAreaId
LEFT OUTER JOIN IaptReferrals R 
    ON C.ClientId = R.ClientId
LEFT OUTER JOIN IaptAppointments A
    ON R.IaptReferralId = A.Referral_IaptReferralId

GROUP BY OA.OrganisationAreaId, OA.Name
```

Let's look at how we can improve it.  First, if you want the average time between the referral date and first appointment, you want inner, not outer joins.  Second, you have a case construct without an else condition.  Three, you have something about appointments booked which seem irrelevent.  Finally, you got an error message for bad syntax.

To fix the last error, move the min appointment date to a subquery.  That will make your query look like this:

```
select oa.name
, avg(datediff(d, ReferralRequestReceivedDate, MinAppointmentDate)) 
AvgAllocationWaitTime

from OrganisationAreas oa 
JOIN Clients C
    ON OA.OrganisationAreaId = C.OrganisationAreaId
JOIN IaptReferrals R 
    ON C.ClientId = R.ClientId
join (
select referral_iaptReferralId refid
, min(appointmentdate) MinAppointmentDate
from IaptAppointments
where clause goes here
group by referral_iaptReferralId
) temp on refid = r.iaptReferralId

where clause goes here
```

Keep this basic structure.  If you want an appointment count as well, try to keep it simple.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for the help. I used outer joins because I still want the area to be returned whether there are any referrals assigned to it so I can display zero counts. Cheers for the help folks. I'll try and get my head around the CTE functionality, looks powerful.